# If i wanted to compare 3 Variables using if elif statement, how would I do it?

Tags: python, if-statement

Ex:

```
A-homework average 
B-quiz average 
C-course average

If a and b and c > 60:
   Print('you passed all with flying colors, not one failing grade.
```

But if they have passing grades on a and b but not c, how would that look like/work?

Comment: That doesn't do what you think, you may want `if a> 60 and b> 60 and c > 60:`

Comment: `if all(i > 60 for i in (a, b, c)):`